# Exit app and constructor no longer called on Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a constructor with data to be loaded when the Application run for the first time. However when I press back to exit my application, I can no longer load the constructor once I launch the application again. However this problem will not exist when I press the window button and proceed to select my application. The constructor data will still be loaded for this scenario:

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        loadData();
    }
```

Comment: And what exactly is your issue? How would you like to work?

Comment: The issue here is that the constructor is not being called once i exit the app by press the back button and start the app again.

Comment: What access modifier you use for your constructor?

Comment: It's basically written on top Public. It's the first constructor and the first page that the app runs when it start

Comment: It runs each time you restart your application.

Comment: ｉ　ｊｕｓｔ　ｆｏｕｎｄ　ｏｕｔ　ｔｈａｔ　ｔｈｅ　ｃｏｎｓｔｒｕｃｔｏｒ　ｄｏ　ｇｅｔ　ｃａｌｌｅｄ，　ｍｙ　ｆａｕｌｔ．　ｓｏｒｒｙ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because some information is saved in the memory.
So if you want to call it everytime you login subscribe to the loaded event.

So in your construvtor write this.loaded += and what you want this will allways be called.